# docker private registry user creation

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have created my private docker registry running on `localhost:5000/v1` but it does not provide authentication, How to have username and password so  that only authorized users can push an image to it.

I am also not able to list all the images present in private registry, all document says running below command will list it `localhost:5000/v1/search` but it gives a blank json response as:

```
{
  "num_results": 0, 
  "query": "", 
  "results": []
}
```

How to resolve this?

Thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 2):

An answer to your first question: You need to use something like [nginx](http://nginx.org) in front of the registry to do the actual password authentication.  There are example nginx configuration files for [pre-1.3.9 nginx](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/blob/master/contrib/nginx.conf) and [later versions](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/blob/master/contrib/nginx_1-3-9.conf) in the [Docker Registry Github repo](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry) for wrapping the registry with nginx; there is more information on [authentication configuration on the nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule).

Comment: Hi Thankyou so much for the response, I had a look at nginx.conf file within my private registry. how it helps here for authentication? I tried creating user account by "docker login <Registry URL>", it allows me to create account but I am not able to make how it is getting used because push and pull works fine without any username and password required. Would be great if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use htpasswd to setup a login with dockers registry image. However, I don't believe they have implemented a search function in this image yet. To create a user, I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

usage() { echo "$0 user"; exit 1; }

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  usage
fi

user=$1

cd `dirname $0`

if [ ! -d "auth" ]; then
  mkdir -p auth
fi

chmod 666 auth/htpasswd
docker run --rm -it \
  -v `pwd`/auth:/auth \
  --entrypoint htpasswd registry:2 -B /auth/htpasswd $user
chmod 444 auth/htpasswd
```

Then to run the registry, I use the following script (from the same folder):

```
#!/bin/sh

cd `dirname $0`

docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
  -v `pwd`/certs:/certs:ro \
  -v `pwd`/auth/htpasswd:/auth/htpasswd:ro \
  -v `pwd`/registry:/var/lib/registry \
  -e "REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/host-cert.pem" \
  -e "REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/host-key.pem" \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd" \
  -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY=/var/lib/registry" \
  registry:2
```

Note that I'm also using TLS certificates in the above under the certs directory. You can create these with openssl commands (same ones used for securing the docker daemon socket).