# Access control for private docker registry

Tags: docker, dockerhub, dockerpy

is there a way to access control for push and pull for private docker registry ?

I have a machine where I am running a private docker registry like this

```
sudo yum install python-devel libevent-devel python-pip gcc xz-devel
sudo python-pip install docker-registry[bugsnag]
gunicorn --access-logfile - --debug -k gevent -b 0.0.0.0:5000 -w 1 docker_registry.wsgi:application
```

I have taken this from the github of [docker registry](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/tree/0.8) under Run the Registry section.

This works fine but then anybody can pull and push to this. I would like to restrict the control of who can pull/push to registry.

Is there a way to do it ?

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use any web server with authentication before registry. [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-four-%E2%80%94-secure-your-docker-registry-with-nginx) the sample with ngnix.

P.S. There is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806558/docker-private-registry-user-creation).

Comment: Is there a way to aplly this authentication on cloud based private registry